# How to change line spacing into UILabel on iOS 9

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios9

I am have a problem with UILabel spacing lines on iOS 9, below is the code...

```
public void UpdateView (){

    lbTitleLand.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    lbDescriptionLand.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect...";

    var style = new UIStringAttributes {
        ParagraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle () { LineSpacing = 8.0f }
    };

    var attrString = new NSMutableAttributedString(lbDescriptionLand.Text);
    attrString.AddAttributes (style, new NSRange (0, lbDescriptionLand.Description.Length));
    lbDescriptionLand.AttributedText = attrString;
}
```

[image: Screenshot iOS 9]

in iOS 8 this is the result, working perfectly

[image: Screenshot iOS 8]

Any suggestions of what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you don't set this style at all ?

Comment: Hi, thanks you for trying to help me. I change the range for 0, 1 and on ios 9  this spacing was applied on line 1. Already in ios 8 whole field had changed spacing.

Comment: Were you able to find the answer for it ? It seems on iOS9 it is ignored completely.